# how to display activity indicator view until a function is completely executed?

Tags: swift, swift3

I am new to IOS and swift. I am stuck with an issue in displaying activity indicator.

```
// In the controller
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        }

        Sync.performSync()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

        }

    }


class Sync {
   static func performSync() {
     User.performUserSync()
     ItemBarcode.performIbSync()
     // few more sync functions
   }
}

class User {
    static func performUserSync(){
       Alamofire.request("\(baseUrl)/api/users", method: .get, headers: 
       headers).responseJSON { response in
       // Fetch code and insert to database
       }
    }
}
```

The problem is the activity indicator view just appears and disappears after 1-2secs. But I want it to be displayed until entire Sync.performSync() function is executed which will take some time. How do I code it that way?

Answer (score 2):

You have this problem because the network request you perform in `performUserSync` is an asynchronous request and hence `performUserSync` becomes an asynchronous function as well, meaning that it returns before it would finish execution.

You have several ways to solve this issue:

1. Only call `activityIndicator.stopAnimating()` inside the completion handler of your `Alamofire` request inside `performUserSync`.
2. Change `performUserSync` and all functions calling it to return a completion handler and stop the activity indicator inside the returned completion handler.
3. Use a framework, such as [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org) to handle the asynchronous functions like normal functions with return values.